# How to define sections on the Fermat quintic hypersurface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

I am considering the following Calabi-Yau three-fold $X$ defined as a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^4$ by the vanishing of a holomorphic equation
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\{z_0^5+z_1^5+z_2^5+z_3^5+z_4^5=0\} \subset \mathbb{P}^4.
\end{equation}
In the following expression (a Fubini-Study-like ansatz)
\begin{equation}
K=\frac{1}{k\pi}\log s_{\alpha} h^{\alpha \overline{\beta}}\overline{s}_{\overline{\beta}}
\end{equation}

I am only focusing on the $s_{\alpha}$.

They are sections of $\mathscr{O}_X(k)$ which means homogeneous functions of the coordinates $z_i$ of degree $k$ modulo $f=0$.
In the particular case of the Fermat quintic, the $\{s_{\alpha}\}$ are chosen to be monomials of degree $k$ on $X$. For example:
\begin{equation}
z_iz_j, \: \: \:  (0 \leq i \leq j \leq 4) \: \: \: (k=2) \\
z_iz_jz_k, \: \: \: (0 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq 4) \: \: \: (k=3)
\end{equation}

That is what I don’t understand : how such monomials can be related to the defining equation $f$ of the quintic hypersurface $X$ where only sum of single degree $5$ complex coordinates appear ?

For $d \geq 0$, I know that the sections of $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)$ are the homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $n+1$ variables, but what does it mean for those sections to be « defined on the Fermat quintic $X$ » ?

I am learning basic theory of complex manifolds not as a professional, only math-enthusiast, so perhaps my question is very naive.
Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you actually want to know? You own post contains the answer to the first question, i.e. how the sections relate to $f$. What does it mean for sections to be defined on the Fermat quintic? It means they are sections of some holomorphic bundle over $X$.  In particular, they are sections of $(\iota^*\mathcal{O}(1))^{\otimes k}$ where $\iota:X\to\mathbb{P}^4$ is the inclusion map.

Comment: Ok so, for every point $z=[z_0:…:z_4] \in X$ , there is a line generated by $(z_0,…,z_4) \in \mathbb{C}^5$. The set of those lines $\Gamma_z, \: z \in X$ is a holomorphic vector bundle over $X$ and the sections are defined on this vector space.  Am I right ?

Comment: The phrase "the sections are defined on this vector space" irks me somewhat, given the context. Technically, the sections are part of a vector space, namely $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X(k))$. If that's what you mean then yes. But the vector bundle itself is not a vector space. It is a family of vector spaces $E_z$, parameterised by $z\in X$. A section assigns to each $z\in X$ a vector in the vector space $E_z$.

Comment: Ok thank you; I think I have a better understanding now.

Comment: That's a start. But if something remains unclear, phrase your question in a clear manner and I'll try to answer it.

Comment: Quaere Verum: as I understand your comment, what you call $E_z$ is the fiber $p^{-1}(z)$ of the bundle projection $p$ such that (for sections $s$)  $p \circ s = Id_X$. And to have a more concrete view,  is an expression like $\sum_{i=0}^4 \sum_{j=0}^4 a_{ij}z_iz_j$ (homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$ in $5$ variables) an example of sections (in the context I defined) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this or not, so I'm just going to comment. A smooth hypersurface in $\Bbb P^n$ is projectively normal, so every section of $\mathcal O_X(k)$ is the restriction of a section of $\mathcal O_{\Bbb P^4}(k)$, i.e., the restriction of a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$.

Comment: I think that "defined on the Fermat quintic " just means that the polynomials in question do not vanish everywhere on the quintic (and possibly that for every point on the quintic, at least one of them does not vanish).